# Average number of skips for a block

Tags: proof-of-stake

Is there any statistical information mentioning the average number of skips for a block in Ethereum's Proof of Stake. Like if the selected(winning) miner is unable to mine the block(inactive) the next one will be selected. In this fashion what is the average of number of skips a block has to go through ?
Can I get any statistical information or any info on official documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ethereum, each slot has only 1 block proposer.  A slot is every 12 seconds.  If the proposer is inactive, that [slot is left empty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/140139/what-is-the-underlying-mechanism-behind-empty-slots-in-ethereum).

https://beaconscan.com/stat/networkparticipation suggests that over 99% of validators are active.  A naive approximation would be that on average, less than 1 out of every 100 slots is skipped.

The [Merge data challenge](https://esp.ethereum.foundation/merge-data-challenge) has some ideas on how you can get data and perform analysis:

- Run / sync a Mainnet client pair (or multiple clients)
- Dig around a block explorer:
  Etherscan / BeaconScan
  Beaconcha.in
- Experiment with client APIs for single node statistic (i.e. beacon-APIs and execution-APIs)
- Experiment with ethdo, rumor, zcli, chaind, Ethereum ETL, Ethereum 2 ETL, and other existing data gathering and analysis tools

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Does the slot time varies ? Or is it fixed at 12 seconds. If it is fixed how is that calculated or proposed to only 12 seconds ?

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  It is possible for future upgrades to adjust the slot time, but currently it is fixed at 12 seconds.  For why 12 seconds, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/149349/why-are-ethereum-slots-12-seconds