# Why are Ethereum slots 12 seconds?

Tags: proof-of-stake, consensus, block-interval, beacon-chain, slots

In Ethereum Proof of Stake, how was this particular slot time of 12 seconds decided upon?

Credit: https://old.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/gb8j89/eth20_slot_time_a_question/

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum slots are 12 seconds to allow a [balance between decentralization and finality time](https://medium.com/@VitalikButerin/parametrizing-casper-the-decentralization-finality-time-overhead-tradeoff-3f2011672735).

Basically, all validators must be able to handle work/load/messages within the slot time.  Shorter slot times would require validators to be more powerful and lead to less decentralization.  Longer slot times would increase the time to finality.

A slot time of 12 seconds was based on benchmarks and an estimate of the maximum number of validators.

Reference: https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/serenity_design_rationale?type=view#Why-32-ETH-validator-sizes

> With a finality time of 2 epochs (2 * 32 * 12 = 768 seconds), that implies a max overhead of (2^22)/768 ≈ 5461 messages per second.

> We can tolerate such high overhead due to BLS aggregation reducing the marginal size of each signature to 1 bit and the marginal verification complexity to one elliptic curve addition (see [Lighthouse benchmarks](https://github.com/sigp/serenity-benches#results)).

---

Credits to 0xTerence Reddit user for the reference.